# Cannot find jpeg.h while compiling Abiword 2.8.6 source code

Tags: autoconf, libjpeg

I am trying to compile the code for Abiword 2.8.6. I run the configure command as follows:

```
 ./configure --enable-static -disable-shared
```

This command ends with the following error

```
 checking jpeglib.h usability... no
 checking jpeglib.h presence... no
 checking for jpeglib.h... no
 configure: error: jpeg.h not found
```

I have no idea where to find `jpeg.h`. I am doing this on Ubuntu on a x86_64 hardware. I tried installing `libjpeg` using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs
```

That did not help. `libjpeg-progs` package did install, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Is libjpeg-dev (or -devel depending on your system) installed? You need the development headers to compile from source.

Answer (score 3):

Is `libjpeg-dev` (or `-devel` depending on your system) installed? You need the development headers - including the libjpeg ones - to compile from source.

On a Debian-based system you'd do the following (as root):

```
apt-get install libjpeg-dev
```

RPM based systems will have a similar command.